# Does Spark Streaming support exactly-once semantics out of the box?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Does Spark Streaming support exactly-once semantics out of the box?

In Spark Streaming web page, I can see that [https://spark.apache.org/streaming/](http://spark%20streaming)

Does it mean when I use Kafka with Spark Streaming , still this is applicable?

Comment: Exactly once semantics doesn't only depend on Spark, it also depends on your input source. In the case of Kafka, the receiver based approach is "at least once", while in the receiverless based approach, it's up to you to guarantee exactly-once, as offsets aren't being stored in ZooKeeper, and there's no Write-Ahead-Log.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov : Thanks, can you say more about receiverless approach or any link would be helpful.

Comment: Read [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/exactly-once-spark-streaming-from-apache-kafka/)